# Windows 7 "Could not reconnect all network drives" on boot

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, samba

Windows 7 won't reconnect to my network drives on startup.

Once it is done booting opening Windows Explorer and clicking each share will mount them.

**Windows 7 Enterprise N Service Pack 1**

I have attempted formatting the windows machine - first thing done to machine was to map the network drives, upon reboot they were disconnected. It is running on an **Crucial M4 64gb SSD**.

The host of the network shares is a Ubuntu-Server machine connected through a gigabit switch. A modem provides dhcp, although both these machines have static IP's defined.

It won't reconnect the drives regardless of whether they're SAMBA shares or NFS shares - therefore I believe it's an issue with the windows machine.

Ubuntu 11.10 (GNU/Linux 3.0.0-12-server x86_64)

I've tried using ip address instead of netbios name for mapping shares on the windows machine,

Also tried setting EnableLinkedConnections=1

gpedit.msc > Computer Configuration - Administrative Templates - System-Logon - `always wait for the network at computer startup and logon = yes`

Comment: You should post the error from Event Viewer.  For all we know, your network port doesn't magically turn on until 20 seconds into login. . .

Comment: Gateway resolution failed on interface {8e9717be-da36-457d-80e0-6c146377100c} for 192.168.1.1 with error: 0x43

Comment: @Thermionix Were you ever able to find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Yeah; stopped using windows

Answer (score 1):

Use the Credential Manager and specify an "Enterprise" persistence username+password

http://windowsforum.com/threads/could-not-reconnect-all-network-drives-problem.3262/

> 1. Goto Control Panel -> All control Panel Items -> Credentials Manager
> 2. Next to the heading "Windows Credentials" click on the link "Add a Windows credential".
> 3. Enter the name of your NAS server ("NAS" in my case) and the appropriate credentials.
>
> The result is an entry that has a persistence type of "Enterprise". This seems to do the trick. (I then restarted windows)

Comment: Unfortunately my credentials for access to the share are already saved in Credential Manager with 'Enterprise' persistence

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem I resolved it by unchecking the *Connect using different credentials* check box when mapping the network drive. This allowed the network drives to reconnect at Windows startup.

[[image]

<sub>click to enlarge</sub>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55UqJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many things to fix this problem including the Microsoft hotfix route but found that the solution below (resetting the TCP/IP) was what worked for me.  After resetting and rebooting, I used credential manager to connect again.  The connections persisted normally as an "enterprise" connection through several reboots.

To reset your TCP/IP in Windows 7 you have to:

```
Open an elevated Command prompt (Right Click CMD.EXE and choose Run as administrator)
Type one of the following:
netsh interface ipv4 reset
netsh interface ipv6 reset
Restart your Computer.
```